# Node.JS process send appears to keep raising RAM without GC?

Tags: node.js

```
  setInterval(() => {
    console.time("SendIt");
    for (let i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
        process.send({
            type: 'test',
            id: i
        });
    }
    console.timeEnd("SendIt");
}, 10000);
```

Performing tests with process.send function, I found that my ram will drastically ramp up and stay that way for quite some time. Doesn't appear garbage collection is performed overly and newly added items aren't re-using allocation. Node.JS is latest and this is through Windows development haven't checked if Linux handles it differently.

Wondering if this is normal behavior.

My master is just listening like this,

```
 Cluster.on('message', (worker, message) => {});
```

Don't believe their should be any reason for this climb in memory

Full Code Example:

```js
/*jshint esversion: 8 */
'use strict';

const Cluster = require('cluster');
if (Cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is online`)
  Cluster.schedulingPolicy = Cluster.SCHED_RR;

  for (let i = 0; i < 2 /*require('os').cpus().length*/ ; i++) Cluster.fork();
  Cluster.on('message', (worker, message) => {
    return;
  });
  Cluster.on('online', (worker) => {
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online');
  });
  Cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is disconnected', code);
    Cluster.fork();
  });
} else {
  console.time("Time");
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    process.send('test');
  }
  console.timeEnd("Time");
}
```

What happens is tests will boost Memory to around 2GB~ each worker and it will drop back down to about 500-600MB and sit.

Where as if I ran the app without process.send use ram sits at: <20MB so just curious where's all this memory. ;)

Comment: Is the IPC channel that `process.send()` communicates with taking all these messages and processing them?  Or are they queuing up?

Comment: @jfriend00  Cluster.on('message', (worker, message) => {}); is mostly what I am using currently to receive the messages. I don't believe I am queuing or needing to process the messages but it'd appear something like that is occurring. Is there a correct way to know/handle this?

Comment: Just make sure the target for the message has a listener for it so the message can go somewhere and not get stuck in a queue.  I don't actually know how nodejs handles an IPC message like this if there isn't a listener set up for it, so this is just something to rule out.

Comment: Since you've now disclosed you're doing this as part of cluster, you may want to show enough code that someone could reproduce this in that circumstance.  The code you show now can't even run by itself because `process.send` is undefined for a single nodejs process.  So this code has to be from some child process or cluster process to even work.

Comment: I can repro that, similar memory usage. However, is it just testing or you have a real scenario where you call `send` in a sync loop that many times? I tried to make the loop async by adding a setTimeout(0) promise (so that both master and worker are async) and it looks like send is slower but there's no memory pressure at all.

Comment: So, since this is not steadily increasing memory usage forever, but does reach a steady-state level, this is just the working set of memory for what you're doing.  Clusters are each entirely separate nodejs processes, each with their own V8 interpreter, heaps and so on.  The nodejs garbage collector collects memory no longer in use, but only some of that is given back to the OS, the rest sits in the heap as an unused item available for reuse by future activity.  The fact that memory usage hits a steady state level means that GC is working.

Comment: And, doing anything in a tight loop like `for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)` will cause ALL the objects created by that loop to exist in memory at once because the GC won't normally run during that loop (as it normally waits for idle time to do its thing).  Trying to run giant loops of synchronous code in a memory efficient way is frankly not something nodejs (or probably any garbage collected language) is good at.

Comment: I'd need to confirm slowing it down has no affect like this, but my usage will be for many-to-many servers and routing first need to vertically scale up my MQ I'm building for this purpose. So trying to be very efficient on high demand times and not dummy a machines entire memory if it doesn't need it. :D

Comment: Yeah, but is `for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)` realistic to your app?  That's probably creating several million Javascript objects (I'm assuming that `process.send()` creates multiple objects in doing its work).  If you are doing massive loops of `process.send()`, then redesign that to send large batches of data at once rather than a zillion small objects.  That will be a lot more memory efficient.

Comment: Not in this case, but I do have about 20K users, they fire off a lot of requests so running a comparable hit on the server was all that was, I've used setInterval and WS inputs to engage and get numbers differently.

Comment: Okay, I see GC happening very slowly. It took an hour but everything dropped to <20MB memory. So I take it this was the pressure related and to preserve memory for future events?